# RuntimeError : nnz of the result is too large

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Can someone explain why I am getting the error *'nnz of the result is too large*' and how to resolve it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
row_idx = np.random.randint(0, 19380, 430097996, dtype= np.uint64)
col_idx = np.random.randint(0,  137000, 430097996, dtype= np.uint64)
values = np.ones(430097996, dtype= np.uint64)
random_p= csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.uint64 )

shape1=(137000, 19380)
nnz1 =  700969
row_idx = np.random.randint(0, shape1[0], nnz1,  dtype= np.uint64)
col_idx = np.random.randint(0,  shape1[1], nnz1, dtype= np.uint64)
values = np.ones(nnz1, dtype= np.uint64)
random_tc= csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.uint64)
random_tc*random_p
```

This code results in the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-86c7a6e80653> in <module>
     12 values = np.ones(nnz1, dtype= np.uint64)
     13 random_tc= csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.uint64)
---> 14 random_tc*random_p

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    478             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    479                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 480             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    481 
    482         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    503 
    504         fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_maxnnz')
--> 505         nnz = fn(M, N,
    506                  np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
    507                  np.asarray(self.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),

RuntimeError: nnz of the result is too large
```

[This](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12495) suggested to use Integer but that didn't resolve the issue. I also tried other types of sparse matrices such as bsr_matrix, and coo_matrix and still the problem exists.

Comment: Full traceback please!  Randomly trying other sparse types doesn't help if you don't understand the error.

Comment: I can't help you by reproducing the code since the first `row_idx` calc hits a memory error (Kill) on my modest machine.  For what it's worth, using `uint64` doesn't help since the matrix rows/cols dtypes will endup either `int32` or `int64`.

Comment: The link you provided has a clear solution. Steal `convert_to_64bit_indices()` and run it on both `random_tc` and `random_p` before you do the multiplication.

Comment: @CJR I already tried that and it didn't resolve the issue. Did it work for you?

Comment: @hpaulj I just added the error traceback

Comment: @Mina did you use their specific solution or the solution you have above? Because if you pass the indices through the constructor as you've done above it's going to change them to `int32`. You need to change the dtype of the indices directly after construction.

Comment: You should have identified that multiplication as the error right from the start.  At best you hint at it by the linked issue.  Incomplete information can send potential helpers off on the wrong trail.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create matrices as above
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
row_idx = np.random.randint(0, 19380, 430097996, dtype=np.int64)
col_idx = np.random.randint(0,  137000, 430097996, dtype=np.int64)
values = np.ones(430097996, dtype= np.float32)
random_p= csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.int64 )

shape1=(137000, 19380)
nnz1 =  700969
row_idx = np.random.randint(0, shape1[0], nnz1,  dtype= np.int64)
col_idx = np.random.randint(0,  shape1[1], nnz1, dtype= np.int64)
values = np.ones(nnz1, dtype= np.float32)
random_tc= csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.int64)
```

I'm gonna use [this package](https://pypi.org/project/sparse-dot-mkl/) to interface with the intel math kernel library (you also need to install that if you haven't already). The MKL sparse functions are really good IMO and using them in place of some of the scipy functions has some big advantages. The disadvantage is that it does only floats and not integer math.

```
# Set MKL interface layer to int64
# This must be set prior to importing the package
import os
os.environ["MKL_INTERFACE_LAYER"] = "ILP64"
```

Now it's just a matter of calling the function.

```
# Import and multiply
from sparse_dot_mkl import dot_product_mkl

result = dot_product_mkl(random_tc, random_p)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [14]: nnz=200
    ...: row_idx = np.random.randint(0, 19380, nnz, dtype= np.uint64)
    ...: col_idx = np.random.randint(0,  137000, nnz, dtype= np.uint64)
    ...: values = np.ones(nnz, dtype= np.uint64)
    ...: random_p= sparse.csc_matrix((values, (row_idx, col_idx)), dtype=np.uint64 )
    ...: 
In [15]: random_p
Out[15]: 
<19171x136942 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint64'>'
    with 200 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [16]: random_p.indptr
Out[16]: array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 199, 199, 200], dtype=int32)
```

Specifying the `dtype` only makes a difference with the `data`.  `indptr` and `indices` are determined by the shape, not the inputs (at least not these `coo` style ones).

It doesn't even help if I make the matrix from the `csc` style inputs:

```
mat = sparse.csc_matrix((random_p.data, random_p.indices.astype('int64'), random_p.indptr.astype('in
    ...: t64')))
```

The `link` does a in-place change of dtype

```
In [28]: random_p.indptr = random_p.indptr.astype('int64')
In [29]: random_p.indices = random_p.indices.astype('int64')
```

The multiplication works, though the result is still `int32`:

```
In [32]: random_p@random_p.T
Out[32]: 
<19377x19377 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 198 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [33]: _.indptr
Out[33]: array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 197, 197, 198], dtype=int32)
```

I'm not going to try a large `nnz`.

For what it's worth, my `scipy` is 1.15.2.  I don't know if the fix mentioned in the link is there or not.